# yt youtube viewer for other services

Tags: raspbian, video

I am using yt to view youtube videos from a headless pi (set up using these directions: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=8157)-- it works pretty well. However, the backend of yt uses youtube-dl, which supports many other services (http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html). Is it possible to use yt with these other services as well as youtube, or does it only work with youtube?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It only works with YouTube. I have tried it many different ways.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help get the Q:A ratio up. However, these answers you have been posting, although they do include a small bit of answer (eg. "It only works with YouTube") would really be better placed as a comment. Please don't take this personally, it's just not a correct use of answer. Please do continue working to get the Q:A ratio up with this, but **only** as comments, unless you have a full answer available.